# What's the LAG interface period be if the two switches have different periods set

Tags: switching, layer2

Considering a LAG interface between two devices A and B, A is configured to have LACP fast transmission and B to be LACP slow what would be the resulting aggregate interface's period be?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lacp rate` configures the rate at which LACP control frames are sent from an interface. Each side can have its own rate (`normal`= 30 s, `fast` = 1 s).

The fast rate can be useful when the L1 (physical layer) link state doesn't reflect actual L2 (link layer) connectivity, e.g. when an external media converter is used.

`lacp rate`does not have any effect on the actual interface transmission rate (except for increasing overhead a tiny bit).

Comment: So, does it matter if the two sides are set a different rate like ```slow``` on one device and ```fast``` on another as far as the LAG is considered?
Would the LAG come UP at all ?

Comment: If the other side doesn't time out the LAG trunk within 30 seconds then no, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Meaning, as long as the LACPDUs are sent and received within the ```lacp rate``` that the devices are configured, the LAG will be UP and active. Am I correct?

Comment: As far as I can see, `lacp rate` only configures the sending rate, not the receiving timeout. The fast rate can significantly speed up LAG setup when the physical port link isn't meaningful (e.g. with intermediate devices), see above.